# How to select checkboxes selectively via selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

Here is the flow:
Assumption: I have a file (entity.txt) that contains a list of entities (say city names from H to J like Hawaii, Hongkong, Indiana, Jaipur)

1. Launch my web tool that has names of entities (say cities) listed from A to z
2. Selenium automation should read my entity.txt and select the check boxex of only those cities available in the text file in the web tool

Please let know on how this can be achieved.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? No one will write the whole code for you. Share HTML code, your sample file, Python code to get some help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the checkboxes are inside a grid with the names:

```
nameList = driver.find_elements(...) #Select the names on your GRID
checkboxList = driver.find_elements(...) #Select the checkboxes on your GRID

i = 0
for f in nameList:
    if f.text == yourvaluehere
        checkboxList[i].click()
        break
    i += 1
```

this will click the checkbox that is in the same line as the name that matches the search.

I can only do more if you share the HTML of the page.

Hope it helps.